# Unix sockets between C and Python

Tags: python, c, sockets, unix, endianness

Just made a Python program which acts as a server for Unix sockets and when it receives a connection, reads 4 bytes from it.

On the other hand, I made a C program which connects to the server and sends this 4 bytes to it.

file.py

```
packet = connection.recv(4, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
for value in packet:
    if value == '\0':
        print 'A none'
    else:
        print value
```

file.c

```
size_t toSend 84; // Char representation \0\0\0T
write(fd, (void *)&toSend, sizeof(toSend));
```

This makes the python program receive a wrong order of bytes. Here the output

```
T
A none
A none
A none
```

The first thing that came to my mind was that this was the result of endianness, but then I modified the files leaving them like this.

file.c

```
char abc[16]; 
// setting char abc to be 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP' (without ending \0)
write(fd, (void *)&abc[0], 16);
```

file.py

```
packet = connection.recv(16, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
// everything else, wasn't modified
```

And this printed:

```
A
B
C
...
P
```

So this time it was received as it was supposed to. Could someone point me out to what I'm doing wrong? Unless it has something to do with the `size_t` type, I can't think of anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: Endianness is not relevant for `char`s, and I suggest to use fixed size type ie: `uint32_t`instead of `size_t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Python and nothing to do with sockets, but you're right, it does have to do with endianness.

Test you're implicit assumption:  is 84 really represented as `0x00 0x00 0x 00 0x54` on your computer that is running the C client program?  Try writing to a file instead of a socket, and binary edit the result.  I bet you'll see that your native architecture is little-endian, and that the data that was written was `0x54 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

What you're seeing on the socket is simply what you're sending.

Comment: Note, typical windows PCs are little-endian, so if you're running on windows, you can be pretty sure that your data is stored little-endian.

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi W and you are right, it's represented as `0x54000000`. Thanks!

Comment: Since PC is little endian (0x54000000) and pi is little endian, shouldn't pi be the same as PC?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Thanks.  My brain mis-wired when I wrote the comment, and I flipped little and big in my head.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=531 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34581/is-raspbian-big-endian-or-little-endian both show that raspberry pi is (usually) little endian, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly endianness. The bits of a single byte are always in the same order, but the byte orders within a word might differ. And first you send a word consisting of 4 bytes, and they are received in opposite (i.e., big endian) order, but then in the second example you are sending your message byte-by-byte.

Comment: `s/opposite order/big endian order/`